# Regularization with range of hyperparameter in [0,1]?

Tags: optimization, regularization

In regularization theory, we frequently minimize expressions with the following form:
$$x + \lambda y,\ \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$$
where $x, y$ represent some type of functional and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is a hyperparameter which controls the weighting of the two functionals. I'm interested in ways to restrict the range of $\lambda$ to be finite, e.g. $[0,1]$. For one hyperparameter, this can be easily done as
$$\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y, \ \ \lambda \in [0,1].$$

However, for two or more hyperparameters, this quickly becomes quite hairy. One potential expression is
$$
\lambda_1 x + (1-\lambda_1)\lambda_2 y + (1-\lambda_1)(1-\lambda_2) z.
$$

Is there a way to generalize this range-restriction process for arbitrary number of terms? I was trying to think recursively or through the use of some transformation, but I'm stuck. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would a convex combination suffice? For example if you have $(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_r)$, then define $S:=\sum_i \lambda_i$ and $\lambda'_i:= \lambda_i/S$ so that you are regularizing $\lambda'_1x_1+\lambda'_2x_2+\cdots$.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it's not ideal since it introduces an extra hyperparameter. Ideally the number of hyperparameters would be one less than the number of terms.

Comment: I don't follow your comment. In the above example there are $r$ hyper parameters. After normalization, there are technically $r-1$ hyper parameters, since you can write $\lambda'_r = 1-\lambda'_1-\cdots \lambda'_{r-1}$.

Comment: @AlexR. Sorry, I misunderstood your first comment. You are right, although to solve for $S$ one must know the values of $(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_r)$ beforehand. This is undesirable because for the purposes of hyperparameter tuning, it becomes impossible to exhaustively search over all combinations of hyperparameters since they take infinite range. That's why I'd like to find an expression which allows the hyperparameters' range to be finite, so I can search within that range a priori. Sorry if my original question was unclear.

Comment: In that case you'd need to define some sort of parametrization through a single parameter $t$. While you can do so, at this point, I'm honestly curious what your end-goal is here, because any such parametrization is highly adhoc and specialized: you're doing a hyper parameter search for the best solution but shooting yourself in the foot by artificially restricting your space.

Comment: @AlexR. I don't believe it's artificially restricting the space, because for the purposes of minimization, I only care about the relative values between the terms. For example, you can see in my original post that for the case of two terms, the relative values of the hyperparameters are both equivalently expressive, (i.e. the ratios of the hyperparameters in each of the two cases takes value in $\mathbb{R}^+$)

Comment: In that case, can't you just restrict $\lambda_r$ to be in the interval $[0,1]$ (which, I presume you will discretize for your search)? And if you want to normalize the size of the total regularization, you'd still divide them by the total sum, e.g. using $\lambda'_r$ in your loss function.

Comment: @AlexR. Agreed, thanks for the suggestions!